# Is it possible to reuse binary file that I built in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have to rebuild some packages written in C++ whenever I use Google Colab because of the time restriction, and it cost me around 30 minutes.
Can I save the binary file to Google Drive and reuse it for the next runtime?